# Dyno Hours for Hobby in Heroku

Tags: heroku, dyno

I have a confusion regarding the Heroku Dyno hours. I understand that you are given 550 dyno hours for free per month for the Free account. But how much dyno hours do we get for the Hobby account ?

Can someone please clear this confusion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a Free Dyno you are entitled to 550 hours, if you add a credit card you get an extra 450 hours (total 1000). They go to sleep after 30 min idle time.

Hobby Dynos are not free but they do not sleep (always up and running) so you do need to worry about the hours, you will never pay more than $7 (this as Aug 2020).
Hobby Dynos are still prorated to the second so you can spend less if the Dyno is stopped/paused (scaled down to 0).